# How can I extract all literal strings from text in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, string

I need to extract all the literal strings from my SQL server stored procedures and put them in a table. I tried to use [Jeff Moden's](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and other string splitters, but all the code in between the quoted strings gets in the way and is hard to identify as not useful. The most simple example of what I am trying to accomplish:

input = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ('cool','super', 'awesome')

output table:

- cool
- super
- awesome

Here is an example using the sp_help stored procedure.

```
USE master

SELECT * FROM sys.system_sql_modules where OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'sp_help'
```

I want the output to be ONLY the single quoted items contained in sp_help - here is the snippet of sp_help.

```
create procedure sys.sp_help
@objname nvarchar(776) = NULL       -- object name we're after
as
-- PRELIMINARY
set nocount on
declare @dbname sysname
    ,@no varchar(35), @yes varchar(35), @none varchar(35)
select @no = 'no', @yes = 'yes', @none = 'none'

-- If no @objname given, give a little info about all objects.
if @objname is null
begin
    -- DISPLAY ALL SYSOBJECTS --
    select
        'Name'          = o.name,
        'Owner'         = user_name(ObjectProperty( object_id, 'ownerid')),
        'Object_type'   = substring(v.name,5,31)
    from sys.all_objects o, master.dbo.spt_values v
    where o.type = substring(v.name,1,2) collate database_default and v.type = 'O9T'
    order by [Owner] asc, Object_type desc, Name asc
```

The output would be to a table:
 - no
 - yes
 - none
 - Name
 - Owner
 - ownerid
 - Object_type
 - O9T

Does anyone have anything like this already or can adapt one of the common string splitters to ignore the stuff in between opposing quoted items?

Comment: Generic string splitters don't really work for this since you need to find odd and even quotes + also be prepared for the escaping of the quotes (''). I would assume it's possible to do this with recursive CTE, just keep track is the quote odd or even.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? The window function improvements in 2012 might also help you (lag/lead)

Comment: SQL 2008, but this is not an everyday thing so I could port it over to any version of SQL long enough to use new functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small test I made. The find_next function is a replacement for charindex. The difference is that when it's looking the end of the string, it will skip '' to prevent that from ending the string. If that happens it will call itself recursively:

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_next (@str nvarchar(MAX), @start int, @mode int)
returns bigint
as
begin
  declare @pos int
  set @pos = charindex('''', @str, @start)
  if (@pos = 0) return 0
  if (@mode = 1) return @pos
  if (substring(@str, @pos+1,1)='''') return dbo.find_next(@str, @start+2, @mode)
  return @pos
end
```

And a recursive CTE based function to find the strings:

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_strs (@str nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN 
  WITH CTE AS (
     select 
         convert(bigint, 1) as start, 
         charindex('''', @str) as stop,
         0 as type
     UNION ALL
     select 
         stop + 1, 
         dbo.find_next(@str, stop + 1, type), 
         (type + 1) % 2 
     FROM CTE
     WHERE  stop > 0
   )
   SELECT substring(@str, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop - start ELSE 0 END) as Str
   FROM   CTE
   WHERE  stop > 0 and type = 1
```

Simple example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db6e67/1)

Comment: This is good stuff, thank you. I am playing with it now and will provide feedback.

Comment: I forgot to come back to this. This works good. It did get hung up on a few single quotes, but I didn't have time to figure out the SQL fix, so I just removed some apostrophe S language in some comments that I thought it was getting stuck on. I marked as answer, thanks again.